# CSS: Conflicts with z-index between three different plugins, z-index dont take effect

Tags: css

So this is what I got:

http://mysite.com

Now when you press on the big fat blue button at the right with "Make An Appointment" a lightbox appears. Although this lightbox goes under the slideshow and the same with the menu, like the z-index is bigger than the lightbox. Although i have set the z-index to 999999 for the lightbox, and still it appears under them.

What should I do here?

Comment: It looks like your modal and its dimmed background are nested under some other elements, which is causing their z-indexes to not have the effect you're expecting. You'll want them to appear directly in the `body` element, if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root of your problem is the placement of your modal-bg and modal-box.

They're both inside an element with the class "page-content-shadow" -- this class has both a position of relative and a z-index of 5. This means that even though you're setting the modal to have a z-index of 99999, that's only with the context of its parent element's z-index (which is 5 in this case).

To fix this all you have to do is change the z-index for the page-content-shadow class to 100. That will put it on top of both your nav and your slideshow (in Chrome at least).

Comment: You rock! Thanks alot, spend 3 hours figuring it out with no luck and here you go.. :) thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm about to face a similar problem, but I've been ignoring it as best I can.

My plan, although it may not be perfect, is to run a script that will find the highest z-indexes on the page and decrement them by 1 so that my object can actually be on top.

Since you're using jQuery you could use a plugin like [TopZIndex](http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/TopZIndex) or you could simply inspect that plugin and borrow the code that makes `$.topZIndex()` work.

Once you have the objects with the highest z index you can mod their CSS to lower the value.

Using that plugin, the code would look like this:

```
var bastardObjects = $.topZIndex();
bastardObjects.css("z-index",999998);
```

---

EDIT: I'm sorry if I misunderstood, I thought you were saying that you had multiple objects with the maximum z-index and therefore they weren't playing together nicely.